# Need ideas with my music player

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I've been developing my own music player for android (learning to program in android).

My question is when the application starts for the first time, it asks the user to select a media folder to scan for files. Everything works great, but i have around 1200 songs in the folder and the scanning takes around three minutes to complete. The steps involved in scanning are getting files recursively from the folder and i add the complete path of every song to an arraylist. Then adding every item from the arraylist to the database. The fields i add to database are path, title of the song(i retrieve this using MediaMetadataReader), artist, album and an unique id.

Is there a better way of doing this? Any way to optimize this? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

When i run any other music player for the first time, their library contains all of the songs i have along with the metadata. Their scanning only takes a matter of seconds. how do they do that? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you could use Android's MediaProvider that should have all those information for you (if the music is in a place that is scanned - secondary sd cards maybe not) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html Thats how the others do it btw :)

Comment: I'm so stupid. I should have checked the api first. Thanks a lot..

Comment: I don't know of good examples how to use that but [MusicUtils.java](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MusicUtils.java) from the stock media player may help

Comment: How do i mark yours as the answer?

Comment: you could write a nice answer based on what you did and accept that :)

Answer (score 3):

How about you when your application gets assigned a media folder first time, you iterate through all file the way you are doing and get paths only,

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
```

Then create XML file in same folder with some unique name or id associated with your application.

```
<Songs>
  <song>
   <name></name>
   <thumbnailpath></thumbnailpath>
   <filepath></filepth>
  </song>
</Songs>
```

And next time user select any folder you check wether you have created the listed xml file? if not then create for and in future just use this to xml file as a source of your table.

However the trick part is when user changes a media lets say they added new then you have to write a logic to handle that.

## After OP's comment

Well, I don't have any but Google is always there lol. But The other thing I just remember to tell you is. It would be more smarter to let user create playlist, No one likes to go through 1200 songs together however chopping the list into several different playlist which make your algorithm faster to traverse with handful of files :)

Comment: I'm using folder monitor to monitor the media folder but that only works when my app is running.
Anyway, dir.listFiles() is what i use to add path to the arraylist.
Can you give me a simple example for making a xml file as a source for the table?

Comment: I have already implemented a way to let user create their own playlists. I just want to scan all the songs faster like every other music players.

Comment: @Dipesh, as you mentioned you are storing inside database. It seems like that could be an  overhead just for test purposes read all path and write it on to document folder with .txt extension and check water it is faster to write a file or save into database

Comment: I have decided to go with zapl's answer to use the mediaprovider. I didn't know there was an api for that. And thanks to you too, i didn't know using a database would be slower than text files. I actually thought databases would be a faster way of accessing data.

Answer (score 1):

While Craftero's answer is correct, I would suggest that instead of using an XML file to serialize the contents of the filesystem, you instead use an SQLite database to cache the contents of the directory.  This will be a flexible enough solution, and you can schedule a background service to occasionally update the database to look for new songs (or manually initiate a new scan upon the application being opened).  This allows you to have the best of both worlds, you can initially quickly display everything that you've found so far (except for the first time the app runs), and then later update the database (and the corresponding view) with the new files you find.  Note that you will probably not want to be keeping 1200 songs in an Android array, that seems like quite a bit of memory for an app, depending on the data structure used to represent songs.

Comment: I'm not doing Ph.D. I never mentioned what i do in my profile. Where does it say i'm doing Ph.D?